# Error: Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- Catalogo AngularJS services

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, blur-admin

I need help importing a factory in BlurAdmin

I've created all files and on index.html im importing each file correctly.

```
<script src="/admin/app/scripts/scripts.module.js"></script>
<script src="/admin/app/pages/pages.module.js"></script>
<script src="/admin/app/theme/theme.module.js"></script>

<script src="/admin/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module.js"></script>
<script src="/admin/app/pages/tienda/tienda.module.js"></script>
<script src="/admin/app/pages/tienda/categorias/categorias.module.js"></script>
<script src="/admin/app/pages/tienda/categorias/categorias.controller.js"></script>
<script src="/admin/app/scripts/catalogo.factory.js"></script>
```

> My App.js

```
angular.module('BlurAdmin', [
  'BlurAdmin.scripts',
  'BlurAdmin.theme',
  'BlurAdmin.pages'
]);
```

> /admin/app/scripts/scripts.module.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.scripts', []);

})();
```

> /admin/app/scripts/catalogo.factory.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages')
        .factory('velCatalogo', Catalogo);

    /** @ngInject */
    function Catalogo($resource) {
      return $resource(
              'http://127.0.0.1:9090/:service/:name/:id/:cliente/:categoria',
              {service: '@service', name: '@name', id: '@id', cliente: '@cliente', categoria: '@categoria'},
              {getlist: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}, savesingle: {method: 'POST'}}
      );
    }

})();
```

> Then on a controller im calling velCatalogo

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.tienda.categorias')
      .controller('CategoriasCtrl', CategoriasCtrl);

  /** @ngInject */
  function CategoriasCtrl($scope, editableOptions, editableThemes, baProgressModal, velCatalogo) {
```

I know there are lots of questions regarding The Unknown provider with angularJS but probably there's something wrong Im doing but Im not seeing it. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you included `angular-resource.js` in your `scripts`?

Comment: @Claies the order is not important if the dependencies array is used correctly